# Windows Phone 8.1 & MenuFlyout: How to disable zoom effect

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to add context menu (through MenuFlyout) for button:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Item1" />
    <Button Content="Item2" />
    <Button Content="Item3" >
       <Button.Flyout>
          <MenuFlyout>
             <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item31" />
             <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item32" />
             <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item33" />
          </MenuFlyout>
       </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

But MenuFlyout zooms Button on which it opens. How to disable zoom effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you really need a simple overlay without animations, you need to create your own (an UserControl is an idea).